# Installed location of package files

Tags: apt, javafx

The file [list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/openjfx/filelist) shows that **openjfx** installs files in the directory */usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64*, but why `dpkg-query -L openjfx` on my laptop shows the following result:

> /.
>   /usr
>   /usr/share
>   /usr/share/doc
>   /usr/share/doc/openjfx
>   /usr/share/doc/openjfx/TODO.Debian
>   /usr/share/doc/openjfx/changelog.Debian.gz
>   /usr/share/doc/openjfx/copyright
>   /usr/share/openjfx
>   /usr/share/openjfx/lib
>   /usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.properties
>   /usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.base.jar
>   /usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.controls.jar
>   /usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.fxml.jar
>   /usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.graphics.jar
>   /usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.media.jar
>   /usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.swing.jar
>   /usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.web.jar

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjfx/+bug/1799946  it seems it's related to this bug.